# Using Flow for Rollup Summaries

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow

I am creating a flow to roll up Open opportunities that a contact is associated with.

My general concerns with this design are:

1. When a contact is removed from an opportunity they will not be updated
2. A flow trigger will have to be executed across Opportunity Triggers and Opportunity Contact Role Triggers. That results in duplicate code and room for error because of having two open doors to make this happen.

Is using flow for roll-up summaries not the best usage of the tool? I see much room for data discrepancies and I am currently leaning towards using APEX scheduled jobs instead.

Comment: Are you using Contact Roles to associate contacts with the opportunities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. Flows are not the correct tool for this type of job. Use Apex triggers and/or batch jobs to update the rollup summaries. You can use [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) if you don't want to write your own Apex.

Comment: How does DLRS always stay up to date without actually triggering an update to the parent object?

Comment: @MatthewMetros It has two operational modes, one where records are updated via trigger, and one where the code is run on a schedule. The schedule job takes care of changes that may occur because of formulas or other non-detectable changes.